# Что спрашивают у искусственного интеллекта?

Tags: статистика, искусственный-интеллект

Подскажите, может кто видел такую статистику: какие фразы и слова говорят люди, когда беседуют с роботом или программой искусственного интеллекта.

Пишу программку, где человеку предстоит пообщаться с роботом, нужно подготовить ответы на пару тысяч самых популярных фраз. Подскажите, где поискать такую статистику.. Гугл заводит в тупик.

Comment: Даже кино про это сняли
![Hello Computer](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/40/40bf3628ca29b2e341c4687ac4ca29de1090b51d3fcbb3b6a95f41393fa2ccbc.jpg)

Comment: а если серьезно, то это рейтинги поисковых запросов обычно. а если vsys нужен, так поищите, где-то наверное ещё можно найти его словарик.

Answer (score 2):

Попpобуйте сделать так: заходите в гугл/яндекс, и введите запрос "почему в/как/почему/где/зачем/каким образом/какой". Далее смотриье подсказки - это будут самые популярные вопросы пользователей. Также попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](http://company.yandex.ru/researches/interes/), иногда тоже попадается что-то интересное.

И ещё: представьте, что у вас появилась машина, которая ответит на все ваши вопросы. Какие бы вы задали, такие и добавьте вашему боту.

**UPD** Загляните [сюда](http://chatbot.tw1.ru/dialogs.htm).

**UPD 2** [Поговорил с андроид-версией бота в стиле Зелёного Слоника. Ничего не менял.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xbqi.png)

Comment: Начальник! Начальник! Он слона форсит!